# Laravel8 Many To Many change id for custom attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I created a relationship `many-to-many` between `Faculties` and `Departments`(im Working in a prototype timetable problem). For a petition, these tables need a validation code `vcode`. The problems are in the relationship of this, I don't know why the relationship recognize only the `id`´s tables for the eloquent query and not the `vcode`.

attached my migrations and model relationship.

Migration Faculties Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('faculties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('vcode')->index()->unique();
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('website');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Relationshop on Faculty Model

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'faculty_departments','faculty_vcode','department_vcode');
}
```

Migration Departments Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('vcode')->index()->unique();
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('website');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Relationshop on Department Model

```
public function faculties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Faculty::class, 'faculty_departments', 'department_vcode','faculty_vcode',);
}
```

Migration FacultyDepartments (Relationship)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('faculty_departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('faculty_vcode')->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('faculty_vcode')
              ->references('vcode')
              ->on('faculties')
              ->cascadeOnUpdate()
              ->nullOnDelete();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_vcode')->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('department_vcode')
              ->references('vcode')
              ->on('departments')
              ->cascadeOnUpdate()
              ->nullOnDelete();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**I provocate a error for get the query and tested the error (getting id´s table)**.

`faculty::with('departments')->get()` gives me:

```sql
select `departments`.*, `faculty_departments`.`faculty_vcode` as `pivot_faculty_vcode`, `faculty_departments`.`department_vcode` as `pivot_department_vcode` 
from `departments` 
inner join `faculty_departments` on `departments`.`id` = `faculty_departments`.`department_vcode` 
 
where `faculty_departments`.`faculty_vcode` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: If it's easier for you there is also [SO in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing the field names for the `faculties` table or the `departments` table Laravel will assume it's the primary key (`id`) for those tables.

You need to update your belongsToMany method to be:

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Department::class,      // The related model
        'faculty_departments',  // The intermediate (pivot) table name
        'faculty_vcode',        // The pivot field relating to faculties
        'department_vcode',     // The pivot field relating to departments
        'vcode',                // The field on the faculties table
        'vcode',                // The field on the departments table
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Rob91 If this has answered your question please can you mark it as accepted. Thanks :)